# Possible to increment in a for loop using multi decimal point increments?

Tags: r, for-loop, decimal

I am looking to make an incremental for loop using a multiple precision decimal point. I am starting to think that R is not a fan of using multiple decimals in their for loop formatting?

I have tried using the `options(decimals = n)` solution and multiple methods of the `seq()` function which I will show below.

This is what I am expecting to work:

```
for(i in seq(0.101, 0.201, 0.001)) {
   print(i)
}
```

I've also considered running something a little more in depth like

```
for(i in seq(101,200,1)) {
  n <- i/1000
  print(n)
}
```

Ideally, `i` would print out

```
> 0.101
> 0.102
> 0.103
> 0.104
> 0.105
> ...
> 0.201
```

Comment: If you want numbers to look a specific way, you need to format them as strings. R uses floating point numbers and those aren't defined to have a shared fixed number of decimal placers. You could format them with something like `print(sprintf("%0.3f",n))`

Comment: Maybe I should go back and edit it because my reprex is the baseline of what I need. Ideally, I need to read into a function with the argument inside the function being a decimal from 0.101 to 0.201 - for me it's less about the actual printing of i,  it's more about how to create a sequence from multiple decimal points and read it into something else

Comment: What exactly do you want? To me your iterator looks quite fine

Comment: @wusel - When returning the results of print(i) in that iteration, it returns `0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1` not `0.101, 0.102, 0.103`

Comment: Please give feedback about answers so the community knows whether the problem is solved or not

Comment: I feel my response to you was pretty clear in that it isn't returning what I would like

Comment: Is it just a matter of printing the incorrect values (you could check that by multiplying them with 1000) or rather about getting the correct value in general. In the latter case: everythign looks fine. In the former: it has to be something about your global options.

Answer (score 0):

Set your global options:

`options(digits = 6)`